# How would I utilize a value returned from a method and implement it the main method in java?

Tags: java, methods, return-value

Can I pass the return value from a method into the main method then utilize that value in another method? That sounds confusing but let me try to explain it better with some code...

```
    public static void main(String[] args){

        ArrayList<GeometricObject> geoList = new ArrayList<GeometricObject>();
        findPositionLargestObject(geoList);

        System.out.println("BIGGEST OBJECT AT "+ maxIndex +" AREA = 
    "+geoList.get(maxIndex).getArea());
        showObjects(geoList.get(maxIndex));
    }

    //METHOD RETRIEVING INT OF ARRAYLIST
    private static int findPositionLargestObject(
            ArrayList<GeometricObject> geoList) {

        int maxIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < geoList.size(); i++) {
            // AREA OF I COMPARES MAX INDEX
            if (geoList.get(i).getArea() > geoList.get(maxIndex).getArea()) {
                maxIndex = i;
            }
        }
        return maxIndex;
    }

    // METHOD FOR PRINTING SINGLE OBJECT OF ARRAYLIST
    private static void showObjects(GeometricObject geometricObject) {

        System.out.println(geometricObject.toString());
    }
```

Lets say I even instantiate the index in the main method such as

```
int maxIndex = 0;
```

I want the first method called to return the value, assign that value to the variable maxIndex then utilize that value for the showObjects method. Thanks for any insight that can be given to a coding novice like myself. Is instantiating the variable in the main method no good? What is the logic behind the JAVAC execution here?? The curriculum covered in my course feels like this is an enormous hole that needs to be filled. Basically, How do I utilize a value returned from a method then implement into another method?

Comment: Yes you can do that, and that's quite common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables are only containers for a value bound to its type. If a method is returning a type, you can place it's return value in a variable located in another block of code. To provide a very basic example for an easier understanding of how this can work:

```
private String getString(int number) {
    if (number == 2) {
        return "Not One";
    }
    return "One";
}

private void printValue(String number) {
    if (number.equals("One")) {
        System.out.println("i is 1");
    } else {
        System.out.println("i is not one");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 1;
    String testNum = getString(i);//returns "One"
    printValue(testNum);//output: i is 1
}
```

With this example in mind,

```
int maxIndex = findPositionLargestObject(geoList);
showObjects(geoList.get(maxIndex));
```

is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, assign the result of your function call. I suggest you program to the `List` interface. Also, if using Java 7+ you could use the diamond operator `<>` like

```
List<GeometricObject> geoList = new ArrayList<>(); // <-- diamond operator
// ... populate your List.
int maxIndex = findPositionLargestObject(geoList);
```

and then yes you can use the variable `maxIndex`

Comment: and if you need that `maxIndex` in the other method later on, you can pass it as a parameter.

Comment: That is three new questions without any code **and** after you accepted *another answer*. For shame. You can't pass values to a "main" method (except for command line arguments). What "main" method are you talking about? Is **what** true for subclasses as well?

Comment: Apologies I suppose curiosity just got the best of me. I redact my former inquiries.

Answer (score 0):

you can obtain the return value in main method like this,

```
  int maxIndex=findPositionLargestObject(geoList);
```

Code:

```
   public static void main(String[] args){

    ArrayList<GeometricObject> geoList = new ArrayList<GeometricObject>();
   int maxIndex=findPositionLargestObject(geoList);

    System.out.println("BIGGEST OBJECT AT "+ maxIndex +" AREA = 
"+geoList.get(maxIndex).getArea());
    showObjects(geoList.get(maxIndex));
}

//METHOD RETRIEVING INT OF ARRAYLIST
private static int findPositionLargestObject(
        ArrayList<GeometricObject> geoList) {

    int maxIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < geoList.size(); i++) {
        // AREA OF I COMPARES MAX INDEX
        if (geoList.get(i).getArea() > geoList.get(maxIndex).getArea()) {
            maxIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return maxIndex;
}

// METHOD FOR PRINTING SINGLE OBJECT OF ARRAYLIST
private static void showObjects(GeometricObject geometricObject) {

    System.out.println(geometricObject.toString());
}
```